# d3.brush does not work in Firefox or Edge when embedded

Tags: d3.js, swiper.js

I'm using the [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/api/) API. When there's any d3 Chart embedded, the brush receives senseless mouse coordinates, in any case not relative to the container where the click occurs. (That's in fact at least the surrounded svg.)
I'm trying to find a solution but I don't know how I can force d3.brushX to use mouse coordinates which are really relative.
I don't know whether this is a bug or not, it has probably not really to do with the brush itself, rather how the browser pass mouse clicks top-down the DIV's until the SVG will be reached.
Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jx0svuth/1/).

(just for the annoying code rule:)

```
    // Add brushing
var brush = d3.brushX()
```

The second slide contains an embedded d3 line chart example, taken from [here.](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_brushZoom.html)
The fiddle works only in Chrome 75+. 
Not in Firefox 68+ nor in Edge 44+.

Running the chart example standalone, it works in all available browsers. So I designate this post for Swiper and D3 hopefully to get a hint for an solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the problem [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/issues/60) I found out, that I can change the behavior in the point.js routines an an workaround. 
If a D3 chart makes use of an brush **and ** the SVG of the chart element is embedded by a surrounding DIV with an explicite width, mouse clicks will not be interpreted correctly in Firefox or  Edge. In Chrome it works perfectly.
I changed the code like this to achieve that it works in FF and Edge, but lose functionality with Chrome:

```
function reverseTraversal(node,targetTagName) {
    var p = node;
    while(p.tagName != targetTagName) p = p.parentNode;
    return p;
}

function point(node, event) {
  var svg = node.ownerSVGElement || node;

  if (svg.createSVGPoint) {
    var point = svg.createSVGPoint();
    var p = reverseTraversal(node,"DIV");
    var rect = p.getBoundingClientRect();
    point.x = event.clientX + rect.width, point.y = event.clientY;
    point = point.matrixTransform(node.getScreenCTM().inverse());
    return [point.x, point.y];
  }

  var rect = node.getBoundingClientRect();
  return [event.clientX - rect.left - node.clientLeft, event.clientY - rect.top - node.clientTop];
}
```

As you can see, I have to traverse backwards until the closest DIV will be reached, get the bounding  and **add** its width to the clientX coordinate.
Without adding the fixed width, the brush is unusable in the particular case.

To get working with all the browsers, maybe a switch is necessary.
It's not a perfect solution, just a workaround for d3.brushX behavior.